# Django/apache NLTK Permission denied: '/var/www/nltk_data'

Tags: django, apache, apache2, nltk

I'm using NLTK with my Django/Apache application, however when loading a page it returns `Permission denied: '/var/www/nltk_data'` error. I made my user (not root) the owner of /var/www and gave permissions with `sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/`. What else can I do to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo chmod -R o+r /var/www/` This will add read permissions to other.

Comment: It's not about permissions, rather it was about the user. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The apache user trying to write to `/var/www/nltk_data` folder is `www-data`. So I made this user the owner of nltk_data folder then it worked.